# How can i use the results from a function placed into control source and get the averages within another text box?

Tags: function, textbox, controls, average

[Quarterly Averages from text box control sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhf3i.jpg)

I have formulas under the Rate Text boxes (See image above) and I would like all three results averaged for the quarter. This is what I have come up with:

**=Avg("[Forms]![collection_attrition]![jan2016_rate],[Forms]![collection_attrition]![feb2016_rate],[Forms]![collection_attrition]![mar2016_rate]/3")**

I am still receiving an error?

Comment: You have not provided any information about what language you're trying to do this in.  Html perhaps?

Comment: Well, you added what looks like MS Access syntax, but it doesn't really provide much more information about what product/lanaguge you're trying to use.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve